# How to setup DNS to connect 2 servers with 1 Domain?

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm, nameservers, a-records

I have 2 servers with WHM installed. I want to map 2 IPs of each server to 4 Name Servers of my Domain.

```
Server 1 IPs: 1.2.3.4 & 1.2.3.5
Server 2 IPs: 2.2.3.4 & 2.2.3.5
```

So my 4 Name Servers should be like:

```
ns1.example.com 1.2.3.4
ns2.example.com 1.2.3.5
ns3.example.com 2.2.3.4
ns4.example.com 2.2.3.5
```

From what I understand:

- I need to create 4 Child Name Servers at my Domain Registrar and
  point them to these 4 IPs.
- I need to create same account for my domain on both servers.
- On Server 1 I need to add NS1 and NS2 A records to the DNS Zone Entries of my domain cPanel account.
- On Server 2 I need to add NS3 and NS4 A records to the DNS Zone Entries of my domain cPanel account.

Then I will just give half my clients NS1 and NS2 and the rest clients NS3 and NS4 to point their domains to.

Can anyone please suggest the points I shared here are sufficient? As I tried these settings for my servers. Sometimes, the DNS doesn't work for a few websites.

Do I need to add NS3 and NS4 entries to the Server 1 and vice versa?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the dns zone files of the same domains on both WHM servers.

On WHM1 server let's say you have NS1 and NS2 and on WHM2 server you have NS3 and NS4

You domain zone file should have entries for all 4 nameservers like:

```
domain.com. IN NS NS1
domain.com. IN NS NS2
domain.com. IN NS NS3
domain.com. IN NS NS4
```

The best approach would be to use DNS Clustering. You will need at least one cPanel/WHM server and then one or more cPanel/WHM DNS Only servers. With this setup when a new cPanel account is added, the dns zone files will be synced around the DNS Cluster. The WHM server itself won't be a DNS server but will just send the zone files do you DNS Cluster and their members.

With your actual setup, if you add a cPanel domain on WHM2 server let's say, it's added with the 4 nameservers but the DNS zone file is only created on WHM2 where you have added the cpanel account. You will have then to manually create the dns zone for that domain on WHM1 server in order to have all the DNS servers as functional.